# PostgreSQL insert from SQL SELECT statement fails because of expression type text

Tags: postgresql

I'm running into a simple error on PostgreSQL inserting data into a new table. I'd like to use a simple query because this table is only going to store averages across different dimensions. I want my `avg` column to be double precision. My insert statement is

```
insert into benchmark_table 
(select avg(s.percentage_value) as avg, s.metric_name, s.category 
from some_table s group by s.category, s.metric_name);
```

This command fails with the following error:

> ERROR:  column "avg" is of type double precision but expression is of
>   type text LINE 2: ...(s.percentage_value) as double precision) as avg,
>   s.metric_n...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

So I try casting my avg column to double precision:

```
INSERT into benchmark_table 
(SELECT cast(avg(s.percentage_value) as double precision) as avg, s.metric_name, s.category 
FROM some_table s group by s.category, s.metric_name);
```

I've also attempted

```
insert into benchmark_table 
(Select  avg(s.percentage_value)::double precision as avg, s.metric_name, s.category 
from summary_view_output s group by s.category, s.metric_name);
```

However, I get the same error about `avg` being text. I understand that what's being returned from my query is a result set that is by default text, but I'm not seeing any way to convert this into another datatype for my outer INSERT statement to use.

Comment: try changing the ::double precision to ::float? also, maybe the ordinal position of the tables fields are not the same as your select.  try to use "insert into benchmark_table( avg, metric_name, category)"

Comment: yes, this worked. feel free to write this up as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the ::double precision to ::float and see if that works.  Also I noticed you aren't including the field names in the Insert clause. Maybe the ordinal position of the fields of the benchmark_table is not the same as in the select statement. 
try to use.

```
insert into benchmark_table( avg, metric_name, category)
```

Comment: Ordinal position FTW